# Bit window operation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Suppose I have 2 64-bit unsigned integer. I have a window of size `k`, and at one time it starts at the end of the first integer and ends at the start of the second integer. (Of course, I know where it starts)

For example, the first one is `...0110011`, and the second one is `110......` And the window starts at the first `0`, the size of the window is `10`. The output should be `0110011 110`.

My question is, how to write such a decent program to solve this problem? I try to use mask and then realize I got 2 chunk bits integer (`0110011 and 110.......`) and I don't know how to concatenate them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    unsigned long long i1 = 0x0123456789ABCDEFULL;
    unsigned long long i2 = 0x11223344AABBCCDDULL;

    // window start 7, size 12 bits
    // so it should include bits 7..0 from i1 and 63..60 from i2
    int windowStart =  7; // bit 7 of i1
    int windowSize  = 12;

    // Number of most significant bits needed from i2
    int numBitsFromSecondNum = windowSize - windowStart - 1;
    // AND mask of i1 to obtain the least significant bits from it
    unsigned long long chunk1 = i1 & ((1 << (windowStart+1)) - 1);
    // Right shift i2 to obtain the most significant bits from it
    unsigned long long chunk2 = i2 >> (64 - numBitsFromSecondNum);

    // Concatenation of the 2 chunks
    unsigned long long result = (chunk1 << numBitsFromSecondNum) | chunk2; 

    printf("%llX\n", chunk1); // prints: EF
    printf("%llX\n", chunk2); // prints: 1
    printf("%llX\n", result); // prints: EF1

    return 0;
}
```

Window start and size are not as in your question, but I chosen them to be aligned to 4 bits, to easily see the output printed in hex.

In the code above I am assuming that `unsigned long long` (same as `unsigned long long int`) size is 64 bits. C standard guarantees it to be at least 64 bits, and that implies it could be bigger (e.g. 128 bits). It is better to be replaced with `(8*sizeof(unsigned long long))`.

Comment: Great. I never thought I could shift the chunk1 and then use `|` to  concat.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of over-complicated, but it allows more flexibility at the cost of being much longer.

The function signature is:

```
template <typename... Ts_>
std::string see_bit_range(std::size_t p_start, std::size_t p_length, const Ts_&... p_types)
```

It creates and returns string of `1`s and `0`s instead of displaying it. `p_start` is how many bits to the right it should start at (`0` would be the most significant bit in the first variable). `p_length` is how many bits to look at. After that, you can pass in as many different variables of as many types as you desire. I didn't make it check if `p_start` or `p_length` are too large, or if you pass it zero arguments, so don't do that.

Take two variables like so: `unsigned char var1 = 0b00110011, var 2 = 0b11000000;`. Calling the function like `see_bit_range(1, 10, var1, var2)`, the result is the string "0110011 110".

```
int main()
{
    const uint64_t var1 = 0b0110011; //...0110011
    const uint64_t var2 = 3ull << 62; //110...
    const int start = 57; //How many bits from the left to start at (64 - 7)
    const int length = 10; //How many bits to read

    std::cout << see_bit_range(start, length, var1, var2); //0110011 110
}
```

[Like this.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/104ca2766debce44)

The function's code is below. `get_var_sum` is a helper to calculate the size of all the objects, and is otherwise unimportant. It can be left out entirely by using `new` allocated memory instead of using local arrays like I did.

```
#include <string> //string
#include <cstddef> //size_t
#include <climits> //CHAR_BIT

template <typename T_, typename... Ts_>
struct get_var_sum
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof(T_) + get_var_sum<Ts_...>::value;
};

template <typename T_>
struct get_var_sum<T_>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof(T_);
};

template <typename... Ts_>
std::string see_bit_range(std::size_t p_start, std::size_t p_length, const Ts_&... p_types)
{
    std::string out; //The string that represents the bits

    constexpr std::size_t SIZE_SUM = get_var_sum<Ts_...>::value; //The size of all the types combined
    unsigned char buffer[SIZE_SUM]; //A buffer to store the binary values in
    constexpr std::size_t ELEMENTS = sizeof...(Ts_); //The number of elements

    const unsigned char* ptrs[ELEMENTS]{ reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&p_types)... }; //Creates an array of pointers to the objects
    std::size_t sizes[ELEMENTS]{ sizeof(Ts_)... }; //Creates an array that holds the sizes of the objects

    out.reserve(CHAR_BIT * SIZE_SUM); //Be nice and tell the string what to expect

    bool small_endian; //If we're on a small endian or big endian machine
    unsigned long long test = 1;
    small_endian = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&test) == 1;

    std::size_t x, y, z = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < ELEMENTS; ++x) //For each value
    {
        for (y = 0; y < sizes[x]; ++y) //For each byte in the value
            buffer[z++] = ptrs[x][small_endian ? sizes[x] - y - 1 : y]; //Copy the value into the buffer
    }
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
    for (x = p_start; x < p_start + p_length; ++x) //For the bit range specified
    {
        if ((x - y) / CHAR_BIT == sizes[z]) //If we just reached the end of a variable
        {
            y = x;
            ++z;
            out.push_back(' '); //Put a space in the string
        }
        out.push_back(((buffer[x / CHAR_BIT] & (1u << (CHAR_BIT - (x % CHAR_BIT) - 1))) > 0) ? '1' : '0'); //Show if the bit is on or not
    }
    return out;
}
```